# Xcode with multiple configurations not building after pod install

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I have an Xcode Objective-C project that has a single target and multiple configurations for dev/stage/release environments.

[image: project configurations]

After I do a `pod install` I get a compile error that Xcode can't find pod headers and a warning that the pods don't contain all the required architectures.

[image: After building]

I can fix the warning by setting the `Build Active Arhitecture Only` for Pods project to No, but the compile error remains and I still can't build the project.

[image: Build Active Arhitecture Only setting]

I've tried many things, and the only thing that will fix the issue is if in the Pods - Project - Info I delete the Debug & Release configurations (the two without the environment next to the name). That will fix the error and the warning.

[image]

This allows me to build, but I will have to do it each time I do a pod install. What would cause something like this and is there a fix so this hack is no longer required?

Comment: Issue is with Reachability class. Have you deleted this?

Comment: Yeah, its not just the Reachability pod, that's just the first pod it can't find and it break compiling.If I remove Reachability, it can't find AFNetworking. Also, if I remove the Debug & Release configurations from the Pods project it allows me to do a clean build without any errors or warnings so I don't think its a problem with a single Pod.

Comment: Hey, @AndrejKolar did you manage to solve it? 3 years later I am having exact same issue and it drives me crazy... Spent 5h already googling and testing